# Node js ('child_process').exec does not save the file created in the command

Tags: node.js, child-process

I am trying to run a wget command through node js using exec.
here is the command i use in command prompt which perfectly works and all of the files are created:

```
wget -o log.txt --quiet -O temp.txt --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookies.txt --no-check-certificate --post-data="email=myemail&password=mypassword" https://myhost.com/login
```

the cookie file is important for me.
In my node js code i have the following:

```
var sys = require('sys')

var exec = require('child_process').exec;

function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }

exec("wget -o log.txt --quiet -O temp.txt --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookies.txt --no-check-certificate --post-data=\"email=myemail&password=mypassword\" https://myhost.com/login", puts);
```

the return code is 0 but no file is created in the directory.
I was wondering if you could tell me how i can fix this part of my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`exec`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) accepts a `cwd` option to control the working directory the process is spawned relative to. If one is not specified, the directory where the `node` command was called will be the default directory.

Consider the following:

```
var theCWD = process.cwd();
// var theCWD = __dirname; 
exec('...',{
    cwd: theCWD
});
```

[`process.cwd()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) will get the current directory that the parent process is being executed from, while the module-local [`__dirname`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) will provide the directory path to the script in which it resides.

You may also consider concatenating a dynamic absolute file path in your `wget` command:

```
var theCWD = process.cwd();
exec("wget -o "+theCWD+"/log.txt --quiet -O "+theCWD+"/temp.txt ....",puts);
```

---

I came up with a working example (executing it on a CentOS box):

```
[user@host ~]$ node --version
v0.10.26

[user@host ~]$ cat /tmp/wget.js
require('child_process').exec('wget -o log.txt --quiet -O tmp.txt http://wtfismyip.com/text',{cwd:__dirname},console.log);

[user@host ~]$ pwd
/home/user

[user@host ~]$ node /tmp/wget.js
null '' ''

[user@host ~]$ ls -a
.  ..

[user@host ~]$ ls -a /tmp
.  ..  log.txt  tmp.txt  wget.js

[user@host ~]$ cat /tmp/{log,tmp}.txt
127.0.0.1
```